# How to figure out Expensive measure or layout pass in systrace React native profiling?

Tags: android, multithreading, performance, react-native, systrace

I am profiling my react native app using systrace. When I select dropped frames there are mainly two alerts mostly

1. Expensive measure/layout pass

   Description : Measure/Layout took a significant time, contributing to jank. Avoid triggering layout during animations.
2. Scheduling Delay

   Description : Work to produce this frame was descheduled for several milliseconds, contributing to jank. Ensure that code on the UI thread doesn't block on work being done on other threads, and that background threads (doing e.g. network or bitmap loading) are running at android.os.Process#THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND or lower so they are less likely to interrupt the UI thread. These background threads should show up with a priority number of 130 or higher in the scheduling section under the Kernel process.

How can I figure out where I can optimize and How to proceed If I get some other alerts like this (like any methods to follow) ?

Comment: hey @Dinesh did you find the anything on this. I'm stuck too on similar problem.

Comment: Facing the same issue, any findings?